# How to check status in response from HTTP call

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to navigate to next page if status code is 200 or response is true. But getting undefined in response.status. If I just log only response I get

```
{success: true, message: "login successful"}
```

This below code is getting undefined in console log. I am beginner to Angular and not using any service.

```
goToHome() {
    console.log(this.login);
    this.Http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', this.login).subscribe((response: Response) => {
      console.log(response.status);
      // if (resp.status === 200) {
      //   this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage);
      // } else {
      //   const toast = this.toastController.create({
      //     message: 'User not found please try again',
      //     duration: 2000
      //   });
      //   toast.present();
      // }
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add options to your request, and set `observe: 'response'` to read full response.

```
this.Http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', this.login, { observe: 'response' })
    .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
    })
```

More info in documentation: [Reading the full response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Answer (score 4):

You should use [observe](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) option (`{observe: 'response'}`) to get a full response that includes the response status code:

```
goToHome() {
    this.Http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/login', this.login, {observe: 'response'})
        .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log(response.status);
        })
}
```

Comment: I got error, however thanks for help other answer solved my problem ----
Argument of type '(response: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: HttpResponse<Object>) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'HttpResponse<Object>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': redirected, trailer, bodyUsed, arrayBuffer, and 4 more. [2345]

Comment: Sorry, I have removed the faulty type definition (which causes the error) from the answer.